# How to correctly add variables? Improper outputs?

Tags: javascript, html, addition

My code is to find a random number between two numbers, In context they will be frequencies. But im stuck not displaying the correct values? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
  function noteFinder() {
  var x = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  var i = Math.random() * ((x*2) - x);

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= i + x;
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML= x;
}
```

So instead of showing "demo" as x + i it is only outputting i. Here is the html if that could be something as well as the codepen project [https://codepen.io/bazookajo66/pen/MPYVJW]

```
<input type="number" id="userInput"=> </input>
<button onclick="noteFinder()">Submit</button>

<p id="demo"></p>   
<p id="demo2"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that .value is always a string; the easiest way to convert a string to a number with Javascript is with a plus +:

```js
function noteFinder() {
  var x = +document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  var i = Math.random() * x;

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = i + x;
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = x;
}
```